Mostrar el valor min de la poblacion segun pais en Power bi
Buenas,

Deseo obtener el valor min de la poblacion segun pais:



Tengo en esta tabla pasises que se repiten y deseo el min valor pero segun pais. En el caso de colmbia seria 10 y el de puer seria 2. pero cuando pongo mi medida de min(poblacion) se muestra el valor min pero de la tabla.

Gracias

La solucion seria:
minimo = CALCULATE(MIN(pais[poblacion]),ALLEXCEPT(pais,pais[nombre]))

